# Task from task group doesn't receive cancellation state when another task from the same group failed earlier

Tags: swift, async-await

I found that Task cancellation state is not propagated when any task from tasks group has failed with error.

In my example the 2 long running async operations starts simultaneously. The **1st** one lasts **3sec** and fails. The **2nd** one lasts **6sec** and completes with success. Both tasks check `Task.isCancelled` state before completion. Actually I see that 6s task is not receiving `Task.isCancelled` state.

My expectation was as soon as **1st** task fails then tasks group sends `cancel` to all remaining tasks in the group. So 6sec task should pass checking for `Task.isCancelled`

Below the source code of long running async operation, it emulates long running executing via `sleep()`. After `sleep()` it checks `Task.isCancelled` state:

```swift
func runLongOperation(key: String, sleepSec: UInt32, shouldFailWithError: Bool) async throws -> String {
    try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "loq")
        queue.async {
            print(" \(key) started...")
            sleep(sleepSec)
            
            if Task.isCancelled {
                print(" ...\(key) Task is cancelled")
            }
                
            if shouldFailWithError {
                print(" ...\(key) finished with failure")
                continuation.resume(throwing: MyError.generic)
            }
            else {
                print(" ...\(key) finished with success")
                continuation.resume(returning: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This async function executes 2 long running operations simultaneously in tasks group:

```swift
func runTasksGroup() async throws -> [String] {
    return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: String.self, body: { group in
        group.addTask {
            return try await self.runLongOperation(key: "#1[3s]", sleepSec: 3, shouldFailWithError: true)
        }
        group.addTask {
            return try await self.runLongOperation(key: "#2[6s]", sleepSec: 6, shouldFailWithError: false)
        }
        
        var strs = [String]()
        for try await str in group {
            strs += [str]
        }
        return strs
    })
}
```

And `runTasksGroup` function starts from sync `viewDidLoad()` function

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Task {
        do {
            let strs = try await runTasksGroup()
            print("all done with success \(strs.joined(separator: " "))")
        }
        catch {
            print("some tasks failed")
        }
    }
}
```

The output

```
 #1[3s] started...
 #2[6s] started...
 ...#1[3s] finished with failure
 ...#2[6s] finished with success
some tasks failed
```

The task which lasts 6sec doesn't receive `Task.isCancelled` state, although 3sec task has failed earlier.
Could anybody explain why the 6s task is not cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep` in `runLongOperation` will not respond to cancelation. And a block dispatched to a dispatch queue will not catch the cancelation automatically.

- Ideally, if the code in the block could be refactored to not dispatch asynchronously to a GCD queue, then the cancelation would be handled correctly. E.g., consider using the cancelable [`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)):

  ```swift
  func runLongOperation(key: String, sleepSec: UInt64, shouldFailWithError: Bool) async throws -> String {
      logger.debug("\(key) started...")
      try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: sleepSec * NSEC_PER_SEC)

      if shouldFailWithError {
          logger.error("\(key) ... finished with failure")
          throw MyError.generic
      } else {
          logger.debug("\(key) ... finished with success")
          return key
      }
  }
  ```

  Or, if you want to log the cancelation, then catch, print, and rethrow the error:

  ```swift
  func runLongOperation(key: String, sleepSec: UInt64, shouldFailWithError: Bool) async throws -> String {
      do {
          logger.debug("\(key) started...")
          try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: sleepSec * NSEC_PER_SEC)

          if shouldFailWithError {
              logger.error("\(key) ... finished with failure")
              throw MyError.generic
          } else {
              logger.debug("\(key) ... finished with success")
              return key
          }
      } catch {
          logger.error("\(key): \(error.localizedDescription)")
          throw error
      }
  }
  ```
- If you are using continuations (e.g., wrapping dispatch to a dispatch queue inside a `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`, as in your example), you need to handle cancelation manually. If you’re wrapping some legacy, cancelable, asynchronous process, you would use `withTaskCancellationHandler`. If you are looping (e.g., doing some long calculation), you would manually test cancelation status with either `Task.checkCancellation` or periodically test `Task.isCancelled`. But `sleep` is not cancelable.

  Let us assume for a second that your task was really a slow, blocking, uncancelable, process. So, a few observations:

  1. Using a dispatch queue takes you out of a context where you can use `Task.isCancelled` anymore.
  2. If possible, I would encourage you to stay within the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool. I.e., use detached task rather than GCD.
  3. You can use `withTaskCancellationHandler` to detect cancelation and update your own state.
  4. You will want to synchronize your access to that state variable. Either create your own `Sendable` state property with some synchronization, or use an actor.

  E.g., below I am running my slow, uncancelable process with a detached task:

  ```swift
  func runLongOperation(key: String, sleepSec: UInt32, shouldFailWithError: Bool) async throws -> String {
      let state = State()

      return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
          try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
              Task.detached {
                  print(" \(key) started...")
                  sleep(sleepSec)

                  if await state.isCancelled {
                      print(" ...\(key) Task is cancelled")
                      continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
                  } else if shouldFailWithError {
                      print(" ...\(key) finished with failure")
                      continuation.resume(throwing: MyError.generic)
                  } else {
                      print(" ...\(key) finished with success")
                      continuation.resume(returning: key)
                  }
              }
          }
      } onCancel: {
          Task { await state.cancel() }
      }
  }
  ```

  Where `State` is a thread-safe type:

  ```swift
  actor State {
      private(set) var isCancelled = false

      func cancel() {
          isCancelled = true
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. [Helped a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452783/455016).