# Why can't I catch a timeout error in this async function that detects if a device is paired with a watch?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I am attempting to write a utility function so that I can know if an iOS device is paired with an Apple Watch with something as simple as:

```swift
    func isPaired(
        timeoutAfter maxDuration: TimeInterval
    ) async throws -> Bool {
```

I came along with this code that works fine… except for the timeout part. If I comment out the code in the delegate, I can never catch the time out error that is thrown by the code. How come?

```swift
import Combine
import os
import SwiftUI
import WatchConnectivity

let logger = Logger(subsystem: "net.mickf.BlocksApp", category: "Watch")

class WatchPairingTask: NSObject {
    struct TimedOutError: Error, Equatable {}

    static var shared = WatchPairingTask()

    override private init() {
        logger.debug("Creating an instance of WatchPairingTask.")
        super.init()
    }

    private var activationContinuation: CheckedContinuation<Bool, Never>?

    func isPaired(
        timeoutAfter maxDuration: TimeInterval
    ) async throws -> Bool {
        logger.debug("Just called isPaired")
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Bool.self) { group in
            group.addTask {
                try await self.doWork()
            }

            group.addTask {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(maxDuration * 1_000_000_000))
                try Task.checkCancellation()
                // We’ve reached the timeout.
                logger.error("Throwing timeout")
                throw TimedOutError()
            }

            // First finished child task wins, cancel the other task.
            let result = try await group.next()!
            group.cancelAll()
            return result
        }
    }

    private func doWork() async throws -> Bool {
        let session = WCSession.default
        session.delegate = self

        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            activationContinuation = continuation
            session.activate()
        }
    }
}

extension WatchPairingTask: WCSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith _: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        logger.debug("Session activation did complete")

        if let error = error {
            logger.error("Session activation did complete with error: \(error.localizedDescription, privacy: .public)")
        }
        // Remove the comment to make things work
        // activationContinuation?.resume(with: .success(session.isPaired))
    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_: WCSession) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_: WCSession) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

class WatchState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPaired: Bool?

    func start() {
        Task {
            do {
                let value = try await WatchPairingTask.shared.isPaired(timeoutAfter: 1)
                await MainActor.run {
                    isPaired = value
                }
            } catch {
                print("WatchState caught an error.")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WatchState

    init(model: WatchState) {
        self.model = model
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Is a watch paired with this iPhone?")
            Text(model.isPaired?.description ?? "…")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            model.start()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(model: WatchState())
    }
}
```

The console:

```
[Watch] Creating an instance of WatchPairingTask.
[Watch] Just called isPaired
[Watch] Session activation did complete
[WC] -[WCSession onqueue_handleUpdateSessionState:]_block_invoke dropping as pairingIDs no longer match. pairingID (null), client pairingID: (null)
[WC] WCSession is not paired
[Watch] Throwing timeout
```

And that's it.

Some notes:

- The task with timeout code is inspired by [Running an async task with a timeout](https://forums.swift.org/t/running-an-async-task-with-a-timeout/49733);
- The code is available here: https://github.com/dirtyhenry/blocks/blob/8ae2f9b90dc3ec26e1cbf16c3b61f13efe5b3c78/Examples/BlocksApp/BlocksApp/ContentView.swift

Comment: Probably because of those floating Task in your start method, it is bad practice to have those. Avoid MainActor.run and use a more natural flow with SwiftUI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425953/how-to-update-core-data-and-then-ui-via-a-background-operation-from-a-button-pre/76426693#76426693

Comment: @loremipsum I tried to keep a reference of the task in a `var floatingTask: Task<Void, Never>?` prop in `WatchState` but I could not catch the error either. Is that what you meant by _floating_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

My answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357087/455016). It had to do with the cancellation of the continuation that has to be manual. Without it `withThrowingTaskGroup` won't return or throw.

So this implementation of `doWork` will do:

```swift
    private func doWork() async throws -> Bool {
        let session = WCSession.default
        session.delegate = self

        return await withTaskCancellationHandler(operation: {
            await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                    activationContinuation = continuation
                    session.activate()
            }
        }, onCancel: {
            activationContinuation?.resume(returning: false)
            activationContinuation = nil
        })
    }
```

Thanks @Rob for the detailed answer.

Comment: A few observations: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/f639bf0aa92c518419169d11afe896f8.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this feedback @Rob. I will update the utility I had extracted from my code very soon here: https://github.com/dirtyhenry/blocks/blob/main/Sources/Blocks/Watch/WatchPairingUtil.swift